# Kurento Javascript Magic Mirror Example - reconnect to server 1 100 undefined

Tags: kurento

I'm trying to run the Javascript version of the Kurento Magic Mirror example, and I keep getting the error: reconnect to server 1 100 undefined.

I'm running on a clean installation on DigitalOcean, so I have a static IP, and the Java version works correctly.  I've tried securing Kurento Media Server using the instructions here: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html#configure-javascript-applications-to-use-https

I've tried both generating my own defaultCertificate.pem as instructed as well as concatenating the server.key and server.crt files.

I think I've installed a TURN/STUN server correctly, although I don't think I need it?

I've tried to explicitly give the KMS address with https://kms_host:8443/index.html?ws_uri=wss://kms_host:8888/kurento

Nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Enable WSS in KMS and accepted the KMS certificates in the browser? Otherwise, your app can't connect to it. Try accessing https://:8433 for accepting the certificates.

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html